# Running terminal through the web browser

Tags: javascript, html, linux, jsp, terminal

I'm struggling with some Web App recently and have a unusual question.
Is it possible to access terminal via the web browser? Let's assume that I have a button, and when I press it I want to have new terminal window appear.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the web app locally, you can tell your server (PHP, ASP.NET, ...) to launch on calling specific url (eg: http://localhost:8080/open/terminal). You can even make a button click event to call that url in the background.

But that's dirty way of doing such things.

**TIPS**: If you wish to use web technology for desktop apps, use https://electronjs.org/